# rviz 'measure' tool

Tags: rviz, ros-hydro

[image: Rosanswers logo]

On rviz, there's a measure tool at the menu on top.
How do I use it? It doesn't seem to be displaying any sort of 'measurement' like distance or coordinates.

Edit: On ROS Hydro.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/199082/rviz-%27measure%27-tool/) by [charkoteow](https://answers.ros.org/users/19824/charkoteow/) on ROS Answers with karma: 121 on 2014-12-07

Post score: 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When you activate it, you can click one time to set the starting point. From then on a white line will follow your cursor, until you click for the end point. The measured distance will me shown at the bottom of the Rviz window.

Edit: I guess I forgot to mention the trick: You can't measure between to random points in the empty space. You have to have some kind of object (TF, Pointcloud, robot, marker...) present, and the can only click on those elements.

---

Originally posted by [Rabe](https://answers.ros.org/users/15571/rabe/) with karma: 683 on 2014-12-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [charkoteow](https://answers.ros.org/users/19824/charkoteow/) on 2014-12-10**:
im guessing that grid maps are random points in empty space?

**Comment by [Rabe](https://answers.ros.org/users/15571/rabe/) on 2014-12-16**:
I'm not too sure, I expected everything that's not the background grid to work. What might help you though is the "Publish Point" function of Rviz, it publishes points to the `clicked_point` topic. I haven't used it exentsively, but maybe you can check it out.